# BASH - Check if file exists and if it does, append the filename to a .txt

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that first looks for a name and then checks whether a certain filename, for example vacation021.jpg exists in the file system, and if it exists I want to append the filename to a .txt file.

I'm having a lot of issues with this, I'm still very new to bash.

This is as far as I've gotten.

```
> oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep "jane " list.txt)

for i in $files; do
  if test -e vacation021.jpg;
    then echo $i >> oldFiles.txt; fi
done
```

This however appends all the separate words in the list.txt to the oldFiles.txt.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit confusing - what would be inside your list.txt files? Your `test` always checks the same file, shouldn't it change each iteration?

Comment: Add output of `grep "jane " list.txt` to your question.

Comment: What process may suddenly be removing `vacation021.jpg` while your loop is running? Wouldn't it be enough to test if `vacation021.jpg` exists _before_ the loop and abort if it doesn't?

Comment: `files` is going to contain filenames with whitespace because there's a space after `jane` in tghe `grep` command. So your `for` loop won't work, because it will treat each word in the filename as a separate item.

Answer (score 2):

`for i in $files` will iterate over each word in `$files`, not the lines. If you want to iterate over the lines, pipe the output of `grep` to the loop:

```
grep 'jane ' list.txt | while read -r i; do
    if test -e vacation021.jpg
    then printf "%s" "%i"
    fi
done > oldFiles.txt
```

But as mentioned in the comments, unless the `vacation021.jpg` file is going to be created or deleted during the loop, you can simply use a single `if`:

```
if test -e vacation021.jpg
then
    grep 'jane ' list.txt > oldFiles.txt
fi
```